# Understanding AVAssetReader and AVAssetReaderTrackOutput

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7

I have the following code I use in my program to extract samples from an audio recording.  I thought I understood this process, but as I read the Apples developer guide, I don't fully understand how `AVAssetReader` and `AVAssetReaderTrackOutput` work together.

Does `AVAssetReaderTrackOutput` contain the track data that the `AVAssetReader` reads from?  When I add the output to the reader like i do here `[reader addOutput:output];` is the output considered the source  of audio data that the reader uses?  In the developers guide it says `addOutput` "adds a given output to the receiver."  What exactly is the receiver?

```
AVAssetReader *reader = [[AVAssetReader alloc] initWithAsset:self.audioAsset error:&error];
AVAssetTrack *songTrack = [audioTrackArray objectAtIndex:0];
AVAssetReaderTrackOutput *output = [[AVAssetReaderTrackOutput alloc] initWithTrack:songTrack outputSettings:outputSettingsDict];
[reader addOutput:output];
```

Answer (score 2):

AVAssetReader is holding the data, to get access to some data you need to read a track. Audio and Video are different tracks.

To get the data out you need to assign a VAssetReaderTrackOutput.

"Receiver" is a acronym for the object in the function (precise is "message"). So

```
[receiver sendMessage:data];
```

Here is a movie example code: http://www.7twenty7.com/blog/2010/11/video-processing-with-av-foundation